# Configure Meteor to store Mongo data of the container and on the host

Tags: meteor, docker-compose

When using docker-compose to create two connected services; one for the app and one for the Mongo data. How do you configure the Mongo service to store it's data outside of the container ?

Answer (score 2):

Take the following `docker-compose` file.

```
app:
  image: image-name
  command: meteor --settings settings-development.json
  volumes:
    - src-path-on-host:src-path-in-container
  ports:
    - "80:3000"
  links:
    - mongo
  environment:
    - ROOT_URL=http://example.com
```

Point Meteor to the mongodb container

```
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor
```

.

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

Store the data outside the container

```
  volumes:
    - path-to-db-dat-on-host:/data/db
```

You can then connect to the db from a terminal using `mongo localhost:27017` or just `mongo` and then `use meteor`